# Wordpress - Linking to images in HTML not working

Tags: html, wordpress

I am creating a website using Wordpress and currently trying to put social media buttons on the header using a text widget to input HTML but the images are not showing and I am wondering if it something to do with file permissions as when I started out developing the website I was trying to upload a header image and was getting the error "Unable to create directory [directory name] Is its parent directory writable by the server?" So I went into termnial and entered *sudo chmod -R a+w /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/sitename/wp-content/* which solved my upload issue.

I am developing locally and when I use an external website as the src for the image it displays the button on my website.

My images are stored in:
*/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/sitename/wp-content/myimages/*

The website files are located in: 
*/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/sitename/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen-child/*

Now the src link should be:
*src="../../myimages/instagram.png"*
but it is not and I have tried other variations even using the full link beginning from */Applications*

So my question is whether this is indeed a file permission issue and if so what permissions should I use and how to enter it. However if it isn't related to permissions what else can I do to rectify the problem?

Comment: I don't know if i understand your problem right but i would recommend 1. please check the "myimages" permissions 2. Why don't you use e.g. the theme directory <?php echo get_template_directory(); ?> or the media library directory to store the images?

Comment: if you will inspect element where the image is not showing , there would be a link...copy that link in url and can you tell us what is that url saying...or is there is nothing in the inspect element????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

either "/wp-content/myimages/img1.png" or just upload the images through the media upload in the cms, then grab the url from there. That makes it quicker also

Comment: Thanks I had already used the CMS media uploader but the link I was using for the img src was incorrect I was using ../../myimages/instagram.png but the CMS media uploader gave me the link `http://localhost/sitename/wp-content/myimages/instagram.png`

Answer (score 1):

you will be success to get images please try this

in you text widget please try to pass the file Path like below:

```
<img src="http://www.sitename.com/wp-content/myimages/img1.png" />
```

befor this please confirm the image location to load  image path to browser `http://www.sitename.com/wp-content/myimages/img1.png`

i am sure this will helps!!